# Can anyone identify what is the name of this plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I found this plant on the side of the street in Melbourne, Australia. Looked like someone just removed it and threw it from their garden. So I took it home and planted it.

The plant had damaged leaves which I removed. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/htnbK.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! If possible clearer, closeup photos (or a description) of the leaves and the stem from multiple angles might be helpful. In particular, I wonder whether the leaves thick (fleshy) and waxy like a succulent or are they relatively thin? ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: There are so very many succulents in the world (and you now have one in your garden!) Wait until the roots have established themselves well, then cut the stalks back to about two inches. You'll be able to post a better identifiable picture when it starts to grow back.